# CSRF token seems to be getting in the way

Tags: python, django, django-views

## CSRF token *seems* to be getting in the way

I am writing django tests for my application, one of my views allows users to "like" other users posts. But the tests are failing, the issue *seems* to be that there is no CSRF token but I'm not sure if that's really it. POST data is not used by the view, it only uses the url data the only reason I'm saying this is because some other tests I wrote has similar problems and that solved it. But nothing I try is working

here is my test:

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token

from .views import update
from .models import Post, Like

def setUp(self):
        # creates a user and logs into the client
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser', password='testpass')
        self.client = Client()
        self.client.force_login(self.user)

--- some code ommited ---

def test_like_view(self):
        # make a post
        p1 = Post.objects.create(title='title', body='body', published_date=timezone.now(), created_by=self.user)

        # get CSRF token
        response = self.client.get(f'/{p1.id}/update/')
        csrf_token = response.cookies['csrftoken'].value

        # send POST request with CSRF token
        response = self.client.post(f'/{p1.id}/like/', {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_token})

        # check that the response status code is 302, indicating a redirect
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

        # check that a Like object was created
        self.assertTrue(Like.objects.filter(post=p1).exists())
```

and here is the view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import Count
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .models import Post, Like

--- some code ommited ---

@login_required
def like(request, pk):
    #users cannot like posts that they have allready liked in the past
    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    
    l = Like(users = request.user, posts = post)
    all_likes = Like.objects.all()
    for like in all_likes:
        if l.users == like.users and l.posts == like.posts:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('..')
    l.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('..')
```

I manually tested the view and I know for a fact that it works, when using the dev tools in microsoft edge I saw that a csrf token was being transferred.

Comment: _But the tests are failing_  You didn't post any failed test output or error messages...

Answer (score 0):

Having a csrf_token and being logged in are two separate things. Anonymous User's still get a token so the server can recognize the client.
I suggest just using the `self.client.login()` command. I've had lots of success with it and I've never had to manually provide a token with any of the POSTs or GETs

##### This is generally how I format my test and do logging in:

- I broke them up and threw in some extra asserts to give you some ideas :)

```py
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.utils import timezone
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db.models import Count
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .models import Like, Post

class LikeCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Note:
        #   Setup is ran for every `def test_`, so you can change the Post obj
        #   and the entire db will be rolled back / recreated for the next one
        u0 = User.objects.create(username='test_user')
        u0.set_password('test')
        u0.save()

        self.p1 = Post.objects.create(
            title='title',
            body='body',
            published_date=timezone.now(),
            created_by=u0
        )

    def test_update_get(self):
        self.client.login(username='test_user', password='test')

        response = self.client.get(f'/{self.p1.id}/update/')
        # Basic Attributes
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response['content-type'], 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, '/path/to/my/template.html')
        # Specific Attibutes (vars passed to template)
        self.assertEqual(response.context['post_obj'], self.p1)

    def test_like_post(self):
        self.client.login(username='test_user', password='test')

        # Should auto-send token
        response = self.client.post(f'/{self.p1.id}/like/')

        # Test correct redirect
        self.assertRedirects(
            response,
            f"/my/redirect/url",
            status_code=302,
            target_status_code=200,
            fetch_redirect_response=False
        )

        # Test object existence and fields
        like_obj = Like.objects.filter(post=self.p1).first()
        self.assertIsNotNone(like_obj)
        self.assertEqual(like_obj.post, self.p1)
        self.assertEqual(like_obj.user.username, 'test_user')

    # Check for Login Decorator - both requests should be denied
    def test_like_anonymous(self):
        url = f'/{self.p1.id}/like/'
        with self.subTest('Anonymous GET'):
            response = self.client.get(url)
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        with self.subTest('Anonymous POST'):
            response = self.client.post(url)
            # Note: Redirect or Forbidden
            self.assertTrue(response.status_code in (403, 302))
```

I always login per `def test_()` as I always test if the login decorator exists. if I logged in during the setup, I would have to logout. I also just make that anonymous test a function, and just pass the URL and `self` (less typing)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include some of my code in question I’ve updated it

Comment: What version of Django are you using? I recreated it on my end, Django 3.2.4, and it all worked with the minor change of the cookie being stored in `sessionid` ..I'm totally going to be using that `force_login` command from now on, so ty.

Comment: I figured out the issue it turned out to be something completely different, it works now.

Comment: @caleballen44 Good enough for me!- remember to post the answer and mark it so others can find it

Comment: Honestly I don’t know what fixed it.

Comment: Bahahaha XD gotta love those! you gain **zero** knowledge, but now you have a copy+paste structure